# The play() request was interrupted by a new load request

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML5  video tag for which user can add a video through input type file component .

My question is that on click of the **remove** link , is it possibe to remove the **video** ??

I have tried as

```
$(document).on("click", ".removepic", function(event)
{
        $("#somevideo").val('');
         var player = document.getElementById("video");
          var currentVID = document.getElementById('currentVID');
      //  currentVID.setAttribute('src', '');
         currentVID.setAttribute('src', '');
        player.load();
        player.play();
});
```

By doing so i am getting

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.playlocalVID @ VM79:56onchange @ VM716:91
```

**Steps to reproduce the issue in below fiddle**

1. Upload any mp4 video
2. Click on Remove link
3. repeat step 1

In server console i am getting

> VM79:56Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was
>   interrupted by a new load request.

This is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/q3hhk17e/30/

Could you please tell me how to fix this issue ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this and its working. I have updated your fiddle also.

```
$(document).on("click", ".removepic", function(event)
{
        $("#somevideo").val('');
         var player = document.getElementById("video");
         player.pause();
         var currentVID = document.getElementById('currentVID');
         currentVID.setAttribute('src', '');
        player.load();
       // player.play();
});
```

Comment: @UnKnown That's great :-)