# The play() request was interrupted by a new load request with the webcamera replay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a code for the moodle where I want to check if user click on video's playbutton, it should grant camera access,
when user click , camera grant prompt is appearing very well, but the problem I am getting is that if user don't do anything video is start playing automatically and pop up is still visible,
I am able to tackle that situation by checking the checking if camera.srcObject === null then video will be paused but when I resume the code again, I am getting the error

`on: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.`

here is the code where whenever use play it will check if cam source is null or not

```
videoTempid.addEventListener('play', () => {
    if (camArea.srcObject === null) {
        videoTempid.pause();
    }
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        // Not adding `{ audio: true }` since we only want video now
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then(function(stream) {
            camArea.srcObject = stream;
            camArea.play();
            videoTempid.play();
        }).catch(function(error) {
            videoTempid.pause();
            // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
            alert('Please provide Camera access: ' + error +
                '\n\nPlease follow these steps to enable the camera:\n' +
                '1. Click on the Camera icon on the right side of the URL bar.\n' +
                '2. Select "Allow".\n' +
                '3. Press "Done".');
        });
    }
});
```

now below is the code where I using pause event, as soon video pause camera srcObject should be null, and its doing that but as soon as user again click on the video playbutton it will giving me the error

```
videoTempid.addEventListener('pause', () => {
    camArea.srcObject = null;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
    console.log(camArea.srcObject);
});
```

well my code is working fine very well. even after this error but I need to reslove it.

I tried searching other questions but didn't work for me

[The play() request was interrupted by a new load request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148998/the-play-request-was-interrupted-by-a-new-load-request)

I tried this but seems they are removing from the videoElement which I can't do. They are getting trouble with the videoelement but I am getting troublt with webcamera